# Reference Request: Fourier Mukai on non Weierstrass Elliptic Fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm aware of the standard results about Fourier Mukai on Weierstrass elliptic fibration.

What I need is the references about Fourier Mukai on elliptic fibration which can have reducible fibers and/or nontrivial Mordel Weil groups, or even genus one fibration.

All I know is the Caldararu's thesis and the paper by Donagi/Pantev on the spectral data on genus one fibrations. I appreciate if you let me know something other than this...

Comment: There is a consensus that one should not post the same question here and on Math.SE simulateneously.(For what it's worth, in this case I doubt you gain anything by having a copy of the question at MSE too.)

Comment: Ok, deleted the question on MSE. I didn't know about the consensus, I thought it increases the probability to get answers, otherwise, there is nothing else that someone can get from these websites...

Comment: If you are unsure about which site is more appropriate for your question and want to try both, the accepted "best practice" is to post first on Math.SE, then wait for a reasonable amount of time, say a week; if after that time you don't get anything satisfactory, you can repost here. The point is that although crossposting might increase the probability of getting answers, it also increases the probability of people wasting their time by answering a question that has already been settled. Anyway, this is not my personal opinion, just an observation about the norms of these sites.